# How can i get an attribute in a page using seleinum on python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to get the content of the element source of one page

```
from selenium import web driver 
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('some link right here')
linkimg = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/img').get_attribute('src')
```

but when i run this code it says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Im tried on python 3.7 and 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `.find_elements_by_xpath()` is always a list of the found elements. Calling `.get_attribute()` does not make sense for a list. Instead, iterate over the list and get your src attributes instead.

```py
linkimg = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/img')
linkimg = [each_element.get_attribute('src') for each_element in linkimg]
```

Comment: It works! thanks, but as im still learning python i dont fully got what you did in the last line, can you explain to more in more details? I dint knew that for loop can be write with this indentation and what this line is doing.

Comment: Search for "inline for loops python". We basically iterate over the elements of the list and call the `.get_attribute` on them. You can mark the answer as an accepted solution if it worked for you!